# QGIS Dynamic Virtual Layer as layer coverage of Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas, virtual-layer, dbmanager

Trying to optimize QGIS for my work, I tried to setup a dynamic virtual layer as a layer coverage of my atlas composition, using DB Manager. I join a vector file to a txt file to use one polygon as my coverage layer.

[image]

The update of the virtual layer works fine when changing the location of the vector but the atlas coverage location do not update proprely. The button "zoom to" applied at the virtual layer is not working either, even after refresh.

Red Outline = vector layer
Dark line pattern = virtual layer
[image]

Zooming to the virtual layer with the same vector location
[image]

Below the parameters of my atlas composer

[image]

The atlas composer works fine:

- creates as many pages as attribute in the txt file
- Display the preset corresponding to the @atlas_pagename

The only issue is the extent of the map.

[image]

Is there a workaround or an other way to do it?

Comment: Why do you create a virtual layer as atlas coverage? As I understoos, you use the virtual layer to join attributes to geometries, right? But for the coverage, you need only the geometries, not the attributes. As well, can you show us how you make the atlas settings?

Comment: Hi ! I want to use a virtual layer so i dont have to parameter the atlas everytime i start a new project. Otherwise i would have to create a new layer to make the join.
The join helps me to create several page of an atlas composer with different preset layers, using the same polygon as layer coverage.

I don't know how to import images in the reply window but here is my parameters:

Layer coverage: the virtual layer (one polygon for many attribute, creating as many pages)
Preset visibility: set as @atlas_pagename

Atlas composer works fine except it does not zoom on polygon location

Comment: Do not add screenshots here in the comments - edit the initial question to add it there. Still don't understand: using a coverage layer based on a virtual layer makes only sense if you use the virtual layer for a combination of geometries from different layers: is that the case? And: does the query from you virtual layer really create the correct number of features? As I see it, it multiplies the no of. features of layer `site` with no. of features from layer `Atlas_couches`. Best would be to share the whole project to understand how it works, otherwise it's difficult to follow.

Comment: Did you check `Controlled by Atlas` for the map-element?

Comment: Well i use a virtual layer in order to make a sort of dynamic join. If there is a better way i would love to use it :)

Comment: If you really use the geometries of two different layers as coverage, than of course a virtual layer seems to be OK. It's just that I thought that one of the layers contains only attributes, no geometries - in this case, it would not make sense.

Comment: Guess what ? I'm dumb !
The "controlled by atlas option" was unchecked for no reason and i forgot to re-checked it !
Sorry for the inconvenience !!!
Nethertheless you saved me. I was stuck for severals days on it.

Comment: That's what I suspected - glad to hear that your problem is solved!